# Where can I find iOS Enterprise Developer Program terms of use (license)?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, developer-program

Is it possible to see the full license (terms of use) of iOS Enterprise Developer Program before going through the whole process of enrollment to the program?

I know that you can see the license during the process of enrollment to the program but this is at the end of this process, after company verification, etc. However, I would like to check some details in terms of use before going through the whole process. I was looking for this document but found nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html). The key points are:

- **No ability** to distribute apps on the **App Store**.
- Only allows you to distribute your apps to employees or members of your organization through **Ad Hoc distribution**.
- The program is for companies/organizations to develop and distribute **proprietary in-house apps** to their employees.
- If you want to develop for other company than yours, that **other company should enroll in the program** and add you to their development team.

Answer (score 1):

The FAQ and program description are NOT terms and conditions. Not sure if I speak for Piotr, but I'm looking for specific terms. I want to distribute to a selected and isolated group of people and want to know what Apple's terms and conditions are to see if the Enterprise Developer Program will work. It's pretty f-ed up that Apple doesn't provide a link anywhere readily available.

Answer (score 1):

From *Apple Developer Enterprise Program License Agreement* ([here](https://developer.apple.com/terms/))

> “Internal Use Application” means a software program (including
>   extensions, media, and Libraries that are enclosed in a single
>   software bundle) that is developed by You on a custom basis for Your
>   own business purposes (e.g., an inventory app specific to Your
>   business) for specific use with an Apple-branded product running iOS,
>   watchOS, and/or OS X, as applicable, and solely for internal use by
>   Your Employees or Permitted Users, or as otherwise expressly permitted
>   in Section 2.1(f). Except as otherwise expressly permitted herein,
>   specifically excluded from Internal Use Applications are any programs
>   or applications that may be used, distributed, or otherwise made
>   available to other companies, contractors (except for contractors who
>   are developing the Internal Use Application for You on a custom basis
>   and therefore need to use or have access to such Application),
>   distributors, vendors, resellers, end-users or members of the general
>   public. For the sake of clarity, Internal Use Applications do not
>   include third-party applications even if some customization has been
>   done.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the details about iOS Enterprise Developer Program in the URL below.

https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html

Comment: I have seen this page but unfortunately there are not as many details there as I would like to see. I would like to read in detail what Apple understands as "App for Internal Usage".